# Template that shows properties with certain attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating an object template that will show only a few fields of a model class, to be used as a summary of the object.  I created a Summary attribute and flagged certain fields with that attribute.  I can't figure out how to actually determine if the property has that attribute though, because in the object template I don't have the actual property, but instead a ModelMetadata instead.  **How can I determine if the property has the Summary attribute in the object template?**

```
public class Car
{
  [Key]
  public int CarKey { get; set;}

  [Summary]
  public string Color { get; set;}

  public string EngineSize { get; set;}

  [Summary]
  public string Model { get; set;}    

  public int NumberOfDoors

}
```

This is my object templatE:

```
@if (Model == null) {
    <text>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText</text>
} else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) {
    <text>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText</text>
} else {
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    @foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) {

      if(prop./******************** what goes here ************************/
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) {
            <text>@Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)</text>
        } else {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-label" style="text-align: right;">
                        @prop.GetDisplayName()
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        @Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is by changing your `SummaryAttribute` to implement [`IMetadataAware`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imetadataaware%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). This is an extensibility mechanism that allows metadata attributes to provide additional information to the `ModelMetadata` object:

```
public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata) {
    if (metadata == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("metadata");
    }

    metadata.AdditionalValues["Summary"] = true;
}
```

then your property check could be

```
if(prop.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("Summary"))
```

If you cannot change the implementation of `SummaryAttribute` or derive from it, then you could consider using the built-in [`AdditionalMetadataAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.additionalmetadataattribute%28v=VS.98%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the attribute is mine so this should be no problem.  I love MVC BTW!  Combined with AutoMapper, its pretty much what I've wished ASP.NET was like for a long time.